# which signal should I use to come out of accept() API?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have two threads one is blocked for a new connection in accept(), and another one talks other processes. When My application is going to shutdown, I needs to wake up the first thread from the accept(). I have tried to read the man page of accept() but did not find some thing use full. My question is which signal I should send from the second thread to the first thread so that It will come out of accept and also it won't get killed??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a `select` with a timeout, so for example your thread executing `accept` wakes up every 1 or 2 seconds if nothing occurs and checks for shutdown. You can check [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzab6/rzab6xnonblock.htm) to have an idea.

Comment: yeah, but that will make my code more complicated, and which one is better between poll and select ??

Answer (score 0):

**Without using "select"**

Example code worked very well on Windows. It displayed "Exit" when SIGINT raised. You can edit code as suitable for Linux. Almost every socket function is identical except you should use "close" instead of "closesocket" and you should delete first 2 lines of code it is about starting winsock and add necessary header files for Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib,"wsock32.lib")

jmp_buf EXIT_POINT;

int sock,sockl=sizeof(struct sockaddr);
struct sockaddr_in xx,client;
int AcceptConnections = 1;

void _catchsignal(int signal)
{
    closesocket(sock);
}

void thread_accept()
{
    accept(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&sockl);
}

void thread_sleep()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    raise(SIGINT);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ),&wsaData);
    signal(SIGINT,_catchsignal);
    xx.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    xx.sin_family = AF_INET;
    xx.sin_port = htons(9090);
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bind(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&xx,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    listen(sock,20);

    std::thread th_accept(thread_accept);
    std::thread th_sleep(thread_sleep);

    th_accept.join();
    th_sleep.join();

    printf("Exit");
    return 0;
}
```

---

First you can use "select" function for accept functions without blocking thread. You can learn more about select in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select) my recommendation is look at last one and you can use MSDN resources on socket programming because Windows and most of operating systems work on BSD Sockets which is almost identical. After accept connections without blocking them you can just define a global variable which can stop loop.

Sorry for my English, and here is a example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 9090
#define QUEUE_LIMIT 20

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ),&wsaData);

    int ServerStream,SocketQueueMax=0,i,j,TMP_ClientStream;
    int ClientAddrSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr),RecvBufferLength;
    fd_set SocketQueue,SocketReadQueue,SocketWriteQueue;
    struct sockaddr_in ServerAddr,TMP_ClientAddr;
    struct timeval SocketTimeout;
    char RecvBuffer[255];
    const char *HelloMsg = "Connected.";

    SocketTimeout.tv_sec = 1;


    ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);

    ServerStream = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bind(ServerStream,(struct sockaddr*)&ServerAddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    listen(ServerStream,QUEUE_LIMIT);

    FD_ZERO(&SocketQueue);
    FD_ZERO(&SocketReadQueue);
    FD_ZERO(&SocketWriteQueue);

    FD_SET(ServerStream,&SocketQueue);

    SocketQueueMax = ServerStream;
    bool AcceptConnections = 1;
    while(AcceptConnections)
    {
        SocketReadQueue = SocketQueue;
        SocketWriteQueue = SocketQueue;

        select(SocketQueueMax + 1,&SocketReadQueue,&SocketWriteQueue,NULL,&SocketTimeout);

        for(i=0;i < SocketQueueMax + 1;i++)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(i,&SocketReadQueue))
            {
                if(i == ServerStream)
                {
                    TMP_ClientStream = accept(ServerStream,(struct sockaddr*)&TMP_ClientAddr,&ClientAddrSize);
                    send(TMP_ClientStream,HelloMsg,strlen(HelloMsg),0);

                    FD_SET(TMP_ClientStream,&SocketQueue);
                    if(TMP_ClientStream > SocketQueueMax)
                    {
                        SocketQueueMax = TMP_ClientStream;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                while((RecvBufferLength = recv(i,RecvBuffer,254,0)) > 0)
                {
                    RecvBuffer[RecvBufferLength] = '\0';
                    for(j=0;j<SocketQueueMax + 1;j++)
                    {
                        if(j == i || j == ServerStream || !FD_ISSET(j,&SocketQueue))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        send(j,RecvBuffer,RecvBufferLength + 1,0);
                    }
                    printf("%s",RecvBuffer);
                    if(RecvBufferLength < 254)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I think you "SIGINT", it is described as "Interactive attention signal" but after signal function is ended, program return to where it left. And far as I know signals will interrupt main thread not sub threads.

Comment: you can send a signal to a particular thread using pthread_kill, and the default action of SIGINT is kill :). which i don't want and even if I handle this signal as you said program will return to where it left :(.

Comment: @AmitBhaira did you tried use "goto" ? I know it is not beautiful but it must work.

Comment: ?? i didn't get you !!

Comment: I edited my answer, I wrote a code without using "select" and I used "SIGINT" for closing sockets.